# adding and removing class is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php code where it displays buttons from A-Z:

```
  <table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">
    <tr class="answer">
    <td>3. Answer</td>
    <td>
        <?php
            $a = range("A","Z");
        ?>

        <table id="answerSection">
            <tr>

        <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach($a as $key => $val){
                if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
                echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
                if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
                $i++;
            }
        ?>

...
```

Now these buttons should turn on and turn off using ".answerBtnsOn" and ".answerBtnsOff"

The problem I have is that it highlights the buttons which should be turned on, but it doesn't unhighlight (turn off) the other buttons. So if button B was highlighted but now the answer is A and C, it should turn on only buttons A and C and all other buttons should be turned off but this doesn't happen as button B is still turned on along with A and C.

So my question is that how can I turn off the buttons that should turned off. At the moment it is turning on the correct buttons but not turning off the other buttons.

Below is current code:

```
var answers = $.map(btn.split(''),function(chr){   return "#answer"+chr;  }).join(', ');

        $(answers).removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');
        $(answers).addClass("answerBtnsOn").siblings().addClass('answerBtnsOff');
```

UPDATE:

Here is a [DEMO](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text12.php) so you can see what is happening, pease follow the steps below in order to use the demo:

- Step 1: On the left hand side you will see a green plus button, click
  on this button and a modal window will appear.
- Step 2: In the search bar in the modal window you will see a search
  bar, type in "AAA" and submit.
- Step 3: You will see a bunch of results appear for you search. In the
  first row you will see an "Answer" column which states "B" under that
  column within that first row. Click on the "Add" button to add that
  row.
- Step 4: You will now see on the right hand side, the button "B" is
  highlighted.

This is fine at moment, but the problem is now coming up:

- Step 5: Click on the green plus button again in the row and perform
  the same search.
- Step 6: This time add the second row where the "Answer" is "A C". Now
  as you can see the buttons A and C are highlighted but button B is
  still highlighted, it should be turned off.

So that is my problem, in this example why doesn't button "B" turn off as it is now not the answer?

Comment: I don't understand the last two lines in the snippet you provided. You are removing the on class from selected answers then adding the off class for selected answers, then adding the on class to all of those and the off to the ones that aren't the selected answers. That means the selected answers have both the on and off class, and all others have the off class. I would expect it to be doing the opposite of what you are seeing, depending on CSS of course.

Comment: If you could supply a jsfiddle that would be better, but it looks like your not actually removing the class "answerBtnsOff"

Comment: @KevinB Im trying to say remove all on classes and add all off classes to all buttons, then add on class to only selected buttons and off class to other buttons. So lets say there r 3 buttons, A B C, and B button is selected, then it should be button A is off class, button B is on class and button C is off class. Then if I want to change answer, then all buttons become off class and then just add on class to selected buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of removing the class for the `answers` variable, I think you need to remove the class from all items containing the class `answerBtnsOn`.

```
$( '.answerBtnsOn' ).removeClass( 'answerBtnsOn' ).addClass( 'answerBtnsOff' );
```

Do this first, as it removes all instances of that class, then add the class to answers that require it.

You may also wish to refer to the [jQuery manual for `.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for ideas on how to improve on what you already have.

Comment: This does work for all items, but how can I do it for just the `answer` variable as that I only want buttons within this variable to be able to be turned off. I tried `$(answers).find('.answerBtnsOn').removeClass('answerBtnsOn').addClass('answerBtnsOff');` but this did not work

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing with the `answers` variable, but I think what you are trying to do is this: `$( '.answers.answerBtnsOn' ).removeClass( 'answerBtnsOn' ).addClass( 'answerBtnsOff' );`

Comment: The reason I want it to assign it to answer variable is because I have 2 variables which r these 2: `var answers = '#answer'+btn;
    var answersrow = '#answer'+btn+'Row';` Now both of these variables use `.answerBtnOn` and `.answerBtnOff` in their buttons. I only want buttons within answer variable to turn on and off and not affect buttons within answerrows variable, that's why I want to assign to a variable. Will your code in comment only turn off buttons in answer variable or will it turn off all buttons that contain `.answerBtnOn` ?

Comment: The selector `$('.answerBtnsOn')` gets all items with class answerBtnsOn.  To get elements within `answers` variable, you would have to do `$('.answerBtnsOn', answers)`

Comment: so it shud b `$( '.answerBtnsOn', answers ).removeClass( 'answerBtnsOn' ).addClass( 'answerBtnsOff' );`?

Comment: If that is what you are trying to accomplish then, yes.  That will toggle for ALL elements that have class answerBtnsOn, that are children of the elements stored in answers.  Your best bet will be to try it out and see if that is what you want.  If not, you may need to update your question to describe things better.

Comment: I have tried you code but it does not turn off buttons which should be turned off. If button B was turned on, but then Answer is now "A and C", then button B should turn off and buttons A and C turn on. But button B is not turning off so all three buttons are turned on when it should only be A and C